# Word too long that exceeds a div

Tags: html, css

I realize an instant messenger. I have a div that reads the user's message. When the message is long but spaced out of space it works well, nothing exceeds the div.
But if I write "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc" it goes beyond div.

Is there a property to cut a word too long? I try with `overflow` and `text-overflow`, but it's not what I want.

```
.base-sent {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 278px;

   .msg-sent {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     width: 234px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     background: #eeeeee;
     margin-left: 45px;
   }
}
```

Comment: have a look at the css `word-break` and `word-wrap`properties

Comment: Why does `text-overflow` not work. What is the desired effect for cropping the word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `word-break:break-all` property to break the long words without having space.

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

This is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/